# Есть ли простой способ в spring boot подсчитать количество запросов за временной промежуток?

Tags: java, spring

Допустим у меня есть сущность `loan`, у нее поле `country`. Я хотел бы как-то реагировать на случай превышения некоторого числа запросов на секунду времени на контроллер с определенным значением `country`. Существует ли не велосипедный способ это сделать ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [Dropwizard Metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.3/), не надо велосипедить.

Comment: @Nofate напиши это как ответ и приложите пример с решением через эту библиотеку.

Answer (score 2):

При помощи [Dropwizard Metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.3/) можно сделать это примерно так:

1. Создаем `MetricRegistry` в конфигурационном классе

   ```
   @Bean
   public MetricRegistry metricRegistry() {
       return new MetricRegistry();
   }
   ```
2. В контроллере получаем экземпляр счетчика для конкретной страны, крутим его, при превышении порогового RPS что-то делаем:

   ```
   public static class MyController {
       @Autowired
       private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

       public void handleLoan(String country) {
           Meter meter = metricRegistry.meter(MetricRegistry.name("loan", country));
           meter.mark();

           if (meter.getOneMinuteRate() > TRESHOLD) {
               // обрабатываем превышение RPS
           }

           // ваша бизнес-логика
       }
   }
   ```

`Meter` предоставляет [экспоненциально-взвешенное скользящящее среднее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F#.D0.AD.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE_.D0.B2.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D1.8F.D1.89.D0.B5.D0.B5_.D1.81.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.B5) значение RPS для минутного, пятиминутного и пятнадцатиминутного окна. Если вам нужна другая гранулярность, вы на базе класса `com.codahale.metrics.EWMA` легко сделаете свой `Meter`.

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть для одной секунды, а не минуты ?

Comment: Будет выглядеть как копия класса Meter, внутри которой `new EWMA(0.63, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`.

Comment: А что делать с `LongAdderAdapter count`  в классе `Meter` ? Ведь это интервефейс на уровне пакета.

Answer (score 1):

Задача слишком специфичная, чтобы сразу без велосипеда поехать :).
Самый верный способ решения, на мой взгляд, это сделать класс, реализующий бизнес логику по подсчету и сбросу счетчика.

```
public class MetricCounter {
    //период накопления счетчика вызовов
    private static Integer periodInSeconds;

    //начала очередного подсчета периода
    private static volatile org.joda.time.DateTime lastDtRun;

    //хранит счетчик запусков за период времени periodInSeconds
    private static volatile AtomicInteger counter;

    //если counter станет больше alarmCounter, то hasNextRun() вернет false.
    private static volatile Integer alarmCounter;

    //некий метод обертка, который увеличивает счетчик на +1
    // и следит за периодами и сбросом счетчика
    //возвращает true, если укладываемся в показатели, иначе false.
    public synchronized AtomicBoolean hasNextRun() {

    }
}
```

Если всё это еще и обернуть в свои аннотации, то можно довольно удобно использовать в коде.

Comment: Это хорошо, но мне надо не просто время считать, а сгрупировать элементы, которые лежат в памяти меньше секунды и в каждый момент времени знать сколько элементов в каждой группе.